# PHP Object inheritance and method overriding

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, inheritance, methods

I have been doing some PHP in CodeIgniter framwork. I made my own Model class that extends and overrides the default codeigniter one. Which is just below:

```
<?php
class MY_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public $table;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = get_class($this);
        $this->fields = $this->db->field_data($this->table);
    }
}
```

I then made a model for managing languages in the database the code is below. From within Language_model if I echo `$this->table` I get "Language_model" which is what I want. But the code errors out in the parent running "`$this->db->field_data($this->table)`" as the table name is invalid ("MY_Model" is invalid). The code never even gets so far as performing var_dump in the child due to error. Why isn't "`$this->db->field_data($this->table)`" also using "Language_model" as the value for `$this->table?`
Running PHP 5.3.9

```
class Language_model extends MY_Model {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        var_dump($this->fields);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

get_class has a particular behavoir:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class TestBase extends CI_Controller{
    public function nameWthis(){
        return get_class($this);
    }
    public function nameWOthis(){
        return get_class();
    }
}



class Test extends TestBase{
    public function index()
    {
        echo $this->nameWthis();
        echo '<br/>';
        echo $this->nameWOthis();
    }
}
```

will output

```
Test
TestBase
```

using get_class() without parameters makes an static resolution, that could be your problem. get_class($this) should work as you spected, returning the current class name, dynamically.

Add code to check that 'Language_model' exists. And be careful, may be the name is case sensitive and can produce the failure.

It would be better to have the error code. Check your logs. Put a var_dump(table) just before  $this->fields = ...